# using Google sheets as a multi user database

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

i have been looking around online for a way to use a google sheet as a database. How ever all i can find online is using one single account to manage all the created spreadsheets. What i am looking for is to be able to let different users to save their data on Their google account rather than my account.

My question is, is it possible to use google sheets as a multi user database?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: This is not a good idea as Google Sheets was not designed to behave like a database.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible, if you put a option for user to input their own api key. The only method to create sheets automatically need api. and you can not create their sheets with your own key. heres the problem. I will recomended, if you want your user to use their own sheets, please keep a dynamic option to save their own api key.